# How to add subplots in QtCharts?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcharts, qchart

I need to create two graphs (subplots, synchronous) and set the dimensions as follows:

- the upper graph is 75% of the output area
- and the lower graph is 25% of the height of the output area.

Something like this sketch.

[image]

One chart is easy to create (code below). But to add the second subplot - it does not work. I tried to add it through QVBoxLayout() but also failed.

I found an example of what is needed, [How to create Subplot using QCharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534586/how-to-create-subplot-using-qcharts) but it is not written in Python (which causes trouble when trying to translate to Python). Here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#chartType-prop is also not there, and also it is not in Python.

**How to add a subplot and with the indication of the sizes (in pixels or in%)?**

```
from random import uniform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries



class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 680, 500)
        self.create_linechart()
        self.show()

    def create_linechart(self):

        series = QLineSeries(self)
        for i in range(100):
            series.append(i, uniform(0, 10))

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chartview = QChartView(chart)
        self.setCentralWidget(chartview)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create 2 QChartView since in your code you only create and set it as centralwidget, then you must use a QWidget as a container and use a QVBoxLayout to add them, for the height ratio then you must set a stretch factor:

```py
from random import uniform
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 680, 500)
        view1 = self.create_linechart()
        view2 = self.create_linechart()

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(view1, stretch=3)
        lay.addWidget(view2, stretch=1)

    def create_linechart(self):
        series = QLineSeries()
        for i in range(100):
            series.append(i, uniform(0, 10))

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chartview = QChartView(chart)
        return chartview


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! As always, you have the perfect solution.